Something in Chrome steals focus when typing replies in some forums. I think it's certain ads
I've not seen this until the last few months. I'll be on a forum like the AVS Forum, typing a reply, and something else on the page keeps taking focus as I type. It only seems to happen on sites with a lot of updating ads.
Just wondering if there is a good way to stop this?
I guess I could use another browser, but it seems like there was an update or something. Maybe it's just an issue with the software those forums use?
I'm running Windows 11 and Chrome with all the updates.
Windows Version 23H2 (OS Build 22631.3447)
Chrome Version 124.0.6367.207 (Official Build) (64-bit)

I did find something about disabling JavaScript for specific sites but that sounded like it could cause other issues.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

If it's ad related, uBlock Origin will fix it.
